# How to show image thumbnails of categories in homepage of my "Adapt" wordpress theme (free version)

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am using the wordpress Theme "Adapt" (http://www.wpexplorer.com/adapt-free-responsive-wordpress-theme/). Now I want that the categories that I create for my post gets displayed in my **homepage** as thumbnail images with category name.

I am able to display the name of categories in the page by using the code:

```
<?php 
$args = array(
'show_option_all'    => '',
'orderby'            => 'name',
'style'              => 'grid',
'show_count'         => 0,
'hide_empty'         => 1,
'use_desc_for_title' => 1,
'child_of'           => 0,
'hierarchical'       => 1,
'title_li'           => __( '' ),
'show_option_none'   => __( '' ),
'number'             => null,
'echo'               => 1,
'depth'              => 0,
'current_category'   => 0,
'pad_counts'         => 0,
'taxonomy'           => 'category',
'feed'           => 'true',
);
?>
```

My homepage will look something like this : [image]

I am new to wordpress and PHP. Can anyone help me with this and let me know what code I need to add to show the thumbnails in my homepage?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's asking for code without providing any prior evidence of effort.

Answer (score 3):

Try to use [Categories Images](https://wordpress.org/plugins/categories-images/) plugin. which use to display category images with simple plugin short code.